# Same data Insert Only two time in table Not more then two time

Tags: php, laravel

I have a registration form where I want to insert data where one field name is 
`Referrer_id`. Now I want when the user register in if the `referrer_id` means the same id number appeared in more than two rows, it throws an error like. This `referrer_id` also reserved two times. I can't use the unique function here because two users can use one `referrer_id`.

This is my code:

Validation

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            'referrer_id' => 'required',
            'position' => 'required',
            'first_name' => ['required', 'regex:/^[A-ZÀÂÇÉÈÊËÎÏÔÛÙÜŸÑÆŒa-zàâçéèêëîïôûùüÿñæœ0-9_.,() ]+$/'],
            'last_name' => ['required', 'regex:/^[A-ZÀÂÇÉÈÊËÎÏÔÛÙÜŸÑÆŒa-zàâçéèêëîïôûùüÿñæœ0-9_.,() ]+$/'],
            'birth_day' => 'required',
            'mobile' => 'required',
            'street_address' => 'required',
            'city' => ['required', 'regex:/^[A-ZÀÂÇÉÈÊËÎÏÔÛÙÜŸÑÆŒa-zàâçéèêëîïôûùüÿñæœ0-9_.,() ]+$/'],
            'post_code' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
            'country' => 'required',
            'username' => 'required',
        ]);
}
```

And here is the `Create` user function :

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
        $ref_id = $data['referrer_id'];

        return User::create([
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'referrer_id' => $data['referrer_id'],
            'position' => $data['position'],
            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
            'mobile' => $data['mobile'],
            'street_address' => $data['street_address'],
            'city' => $data['city'],
            'post_code' => $data['post_code'],
            'country' => $data['country'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'birth_day' =>  date('Y-m-d',strtotime($data['birth_day'])),
            'join_date' => Carbon::today(),
            'balance' => 0,
            'status' => 1,
            'paid_status' => 0,
            'ver_status' => 0,
            'ver_code' => $pin,
            'forget_code' => 0,
            'posid' => $posid,
            'tauth' => 0,
            'tfver' => 1,
            'emailv' => 0,
            'smsv' => 1,
        ]);
}
```

Please give me logic or any other code which I use in validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from my understanding two users can have thesame referral_id. i.e referring to the person who sponsor the two users. right? so to check if the referral_id is more that two, you can use count() to check like this (am using query buider):

```
//check if referral_id exists
if( $check = DB::table('table')->where('referral_id',$referral_id)->count() >0 )
{
   if($check<3 )
    {
       //proceed to insert into DB
    }
   else if($check=2)
    {
      // display error
    }

}
```

you can try the above piece by changing the values till you get the correct validation

Answer (score 1):

First check counts of referrer_id.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $ref_id = $data['referrer_id'];
    $count = User::where('referral_id',$ref_id)->count();

    if($count<2){
        return User::create([
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'referrer_id' => $data['referrer_id'],
            'position' => $data['position'],
            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
            'mobile' => $data['mobile'],
            'street_address' => $data['street_address'],
            'city' => $data['city'],
            'post_code' => $data['post_code'],
            'country' => $data['country'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'birth_day' =>  date('Y-m-d',strtotime($data['birth_day'])),
            'join_date' => Carbon::today(),
            'balance' => 0,
            'status' => 1,
            'paid_status' => 0,
            'ver_status' => 0,
            'ver_code' => $pin,
            'forget_code' => 0,
            'posid' => $posid,
            'tauth' => 0,
            'tfver' => 1,
            'emailv' => 0,
            'smsv' => 1,
        ]); 
    }else{
        // Display a message here
    }
}
```